# Eden space and Old space utilization 100%

Tags: jakarta-ee

I am using jwsdp-1.2 web server. Suddenly I could see server is unable to handle the new request. 
I ran jstat on the process and i could find Old and Eden space utilization is almost 100%.
Which JVM parameters should I change now to resolve my issue?

```
>jstat -gc 24802 10000

 S0C      S1C    S0U    S1U      EC       EU         OC         OU       PC      PU      YGC    YGCT    FGC  FGCT       GCT   
13632.0 14208.0  0.0    0.0   23360.0  23360.0   176128.0   176123.0  20480.0 18698.0    218    7.324 15948 20963.955 20971.279
13632.0 14208.0  0.0    0.0   23360.0  23360.0   176128.0   176123.4  20480.0 18698.0    218    7.324 15956 20974.416 20981.739
13632.0 14208.0  0.0    0.0   23360.0  23360.0   176128.0   176123.5  20480.0 18698.0    218    7.324 15964 20984.790 20992.114
```

Answer (score 1):

> Which JVM parameters should i change now to resolve my issue?

It seems likely that your problem is a memory leak in your application.  If that is the case, then fiddling with the JVM parameters is not going to help.  You need to use a memory profile to try to track down the bug(s) in your code that are leaking memory.

Refer to this question:  [General strategy to resolve Java memory leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473510/general-strategy-to-resolve-java-memory-leak)

Comment: Thanks Stephen for the information. 
Can you please provide me the procedure how to trace the code which is filling up the memory.
It's a huge application which includes some thousands of lines of code in many JSP/Servlets.