# Tomcat Physcical memory usage keeps increasing and doesnt go down

Tags: tomcat6

I have set the JAVA options settings value for tomcat 6.0.35 as

"-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m   -XX:PermSize Size=1024m   -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:NewSize=512m "

Physical memory keeps increasing for every request. 70 request is coming into server at a time.

It has grown up to 2384,012K and didn't crash.

I have restarted the server when it reach 2384,012K. There was no impact to the system and I don't see any errors.

I have Java application to connect to MQ Series via MQQuemanager. It creates new connection for every request and then closes it.

Also it has JDBC connection to get details from Database.

is there any log generated by tomcat if there is a memory leak.

Please advice to validate it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not Tomcat, you'll need some other tool. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473510/general-strategy-to-resolve-java-memory-leak

Comment: Hi,  Thanks. I am checking with tools to monitor.I am using tomcat 6.0.35 and JDK 1.7. Can it create an issue?

Comment: @user2025698 I have the same problem how did u solve it?